# Thunderbird forgets tags in IMAP mails immediately after adding them

Tags: imap, sync, thunderbird, tags

I hope this Stack Exchange site is the right one.
Since a few weeks we are experiencing unexpected behavior with the tag/flag handling of Thunderbird. After assigning a tag to a mail, Thunderbird is marking it a very short time as tagged and after leaving the selection, the tag is gone.

I've enabled the Thunderbird log for IMAP

```
$ export NSPR_LOG_MODULES="IMAP:4"
$ export NSPR_LOG_FILE=~/tbird.log.txt
$ thunderbird
```

And grep'd the output:

```
tail -f tbird.log.txt | grep FLAGS
```

Sometimes it looks like:

```
[ ... ]:imap.strato.de:S-INBOX:SendData: 615 uid store 35045 +FLAGS ($label1)
[ ... ]:imap.strato.de:S-INBOX:CreateNewLineFromSocket: * 1026 FETCH (FLAGS (\Answered \Seen))
[ ... ]:imap.strato.de:S-INBOX:SendData: 619 UID fetch 35046:* (FLAGS)
[ ... ]:imap.strato.de:S-INBOX:CreateNewLineFromSocket: * 1026 FETCH (FLAGS (\Answered \Seen NonJunk $label1) UID 35045)
```

And sometimes it looks like:

```
[ ... ]:imap.strato.de:S-INBOX:SendData: 48 uid store 34991 +FLAGS ($label1)
[ ... ]:imap.strato.de:S-INBOX:CreateNewLineFromSocket: * 1022 FETCH (FLAGS (\Answered \Seen))
[ ... ]:imap.strato.de:S-INBOX:SendData: 52 UID fetch 35046:* (FLAGS)
[ ... ]:imap.strato.de:S-INBOX:CreateNewLineFromSocket: * 1026 FETCH (FLAGS (\Answered \Seen NonJunk) UID 35045)
```

without the flag "$label1" (its the original output).

If Thunderbird forgets the tag, after a restart the tag is set.

Can anyone tell me, if this is either a Thunderbird, provider or my settings fault is? I guess it's Thunderbird. How can i get more information?

I know another person who has the same problem, according to this maybe not a settings fault.

Btw. it's Thunderbird 24.4.0

Comment: AFAIK is this a missing feature of the Strato mail server. I have the same problem and I will contact their support team.

Comment: I've contacted them. They called me and he said everything is fine and they changed nothing according to this issue. In the past, it had worked and sometimes it still works.

Comment: Thunderbird is currently 38.5.0 so I would try upgrading first.